# Applescript: Repeat statments to remove files (and keeping a minimum number of them)

Tags: applescript, automator

I have a bunch of files in an existing folder, and trying to use Automator to first generate a list of the files, sort them in descending order by name, and then use Applescript to trash the oldest 2 files in order to maintain a total of 4 files in that folder.

Below is the code I used:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if not (count input) > 4 then return
    try
        repeat with i in items -2 thru -1 of input
            # To move to Trash, use Finder.
            tell application "Finder" to delete alias (i as text)
        end repeat
    end try
end run
```

It works well but an issue arise when I have a total of 5 files in that folder; the script would trash the oldest 2 files and I'd end up with a total of 3 files. How can I set up my `if` or `repeat` statements so that I can maintain a total of 4 files at all times, and simply trash whatever the number of the oldest extra files there are in that folder?

Comment: Assuming the last items in your list are the oldest, just change your range to `items 5 thru -1 of input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy *algorithm*

- Count the files and subtract 4
- If the result is less than 1 abort the script
- In a loop delete the files backwards

---

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set numberOfFilesToDelete to (count input) - 4
    if numberOfFilesToDelete < 1 then return
    repeat with i from 1 to numberOfFilesToDelete
        tell application "Finder" to delete item -i of input
    end repeat
    return input -- Delete this line if there is no subsequent action
end run
```

Comment: Why the `return input`? There is no need for that in this case

Comment: @user3439894 That's common Automator habit to pass something to the next action.

Comment: I'm well aware of that and you are missing the point. It's needless code and shouldn't be there. There is no additional actions in his workflow after the Run Apple Script action. Even if there was, passing input serves what purpose since some of input has been deleted.

Comment: @user3439894 How do you know that there is no subsequent action? And the files have been moved to the Trash folder. They are not deleted (yet) and the references are still valid.

Comment: I know because I saw his workflow in another question. Additionally he does not have in the code he posted and therefore he doesn't need it.